# Rsync via windows XP command prompt

Tags: windows, cygwin, samba, rsync

I want to setup rsync on windows XP.  I followed the directions here: 
http://www.brentnorris.net/rsyncntdoc.html

However, when I start the service, it starts then stops immediately without writing anything useful to the event log.  Can anyone provide any guidance?  Or another way to be able to run rsync from the windows command prompt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a go with DeltaCopy and had real problems running it successfully as a service.

Have a look at [cwrsync](http://www.itefix.no/i2/node/10650) though - it looks very straightforward to use.

**Edit:** I've now had a go with cwrsync and it works like a charm! You just put your rsync commands in a batch file, stick it in startup, and you're done. The sample batch file supplied has all the commands needed to set rsync up in Cygwin. I'd definitely recommend this to anyone.

**Edit2:** One more thing to note - at least for debugging purposes, `REM` out the first line (`@ECHO OFF`) and add a `-v` switch to the rsync command so you can see if it's doing anything.

Comment: this looks like it SHOULD work, however, it doesnt.  Here is my SECHAW_TUNNEL command(which i think is the most important)

SET SECHAW_TUNNEL=ssh -vi "C:/Documents\ and\ Settings/user/Desktop/connection\ keys/Public-Key.ppk" -L 9119:127.0.0.1:873 ubuntu@server -T -N

And when I run it it asks me for a publickey passphrase(there is no passphrase) and then fails with a Permission Denied(publickey) error

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at DeltaCopy? http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp

From it's site:

> In technical terms, DeltaCopy is a
>   "Windows Friendly" wrapper around the
>   Rsync program, currently maintained by
>   Wayne Davison. "rsync" is primarily
>   designed for Unix/Linux/BSD systems.
>   Although ports are available for
>   Windows, they typically require
>   downloading Cygwin libraries and
>   manual configuration.

I have not used it, but it looks like it will do just what you are looking for.

{edit}
Ok, since you need to use public/private key pairs, how about a pre-bundled distrobution (cwRcync from http://sourceforge.net/projects/sereds/files/) and different set of instructions: http://rsync.net/resources/howto/windows_rsync.html

Comment: sorry it didn't work since I need to able to use private/public key authentication.